# This Swift w/ SpriteKit code does not do what is intended

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift and iOS development. I was watching tutorials on iOS development w/ Swift and SpriteKit. Following the tutorials I opened Xcode, new project, game, universal; and all I changed was the GameScene.swift. Here is the new code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        var node1 = SKNode()
        node1.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        self.addChild(node1)

        var spr1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        spr1.position = CGPointZero
        spr1.zPosition = 1
        node1.addChild(spr1)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Note: the Spaceship image is provided by default.

So in the tutorials, this code added a spaceship to the scene. However, when I run the simulator, the scene remains blank. What can be the problem? If more info is needed, please say so and I will provide.

Comment: Is `GameScene` being presented?

Comment: Show your `GameViewController.swift` code.

Comment: The GameScene is presented, and the code is being run. I confirmed it with debugging.

Comment: I did not change GameViewController.swift. It is whatever it is by default.

Comment: Any errors? Works fine for me. (Spaceship is loaded - hanging off the bottom left of the screen)

Comment: Also what version of Swift/Xcode are you using? The UIResponder method `touchesBegan` was updated in Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) with the introduction of a native `Set` type to bridge with `NSSet`. I'd suggest updating your Xcode and trying the tutorial again.

Comment: For this old question, note that almost all SpriteKit scenes simply **do not run on the simulator**

Answer (score 2):

It could be running correctly, and you just can't see it on the screen. Depending on the device that you're emulating, you may be showing the spaceship off screen. Try a different, smaller device, to emulate, and check if you can see it.

Comment: @Fattie That is not true. SpriteKit scenes do work in the simulator. Create a new sample project and try for yourself. (Although they do run at very low frame rates compared to an actual device.)

Comment: @Fattie That has not been my experience. I've had dozens of complex SpriteKit games run in the simulator (although not smoothly). Saying that "SpriteKit scenes simply don't work on simulator" implies that all scenes fail to run, which is not true. I agree that in practice running the game on a real device is the only way to accurately test its behavior and performance.

Comment: hey @nathan if the OP's SpriteKit scene wasn't running in simulator it's because SpriteKit scenes usually don't run in simulator.  "That has not been my experience"  that's interesting, but it's an extremely common observation that SK scenes don't run in simulator. Cheers!

Comment: @Fattie No, there was probably a different reason unrelated to the simulator. It is *not* a common observation that SpriteKit scenes don't work in the simulator, because they *do* work in the simulator. Not trying to cause an argument, just trying to provide clarification for future readers who might be confused.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your `GameViewController.swift` and making sure that you see something along the lines of this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            let skView                 = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS            = true
            skView.showsNodeCount      = true
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.size      = skView.bounds.size

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```